# SQL Server 14.0: Convert a VARBINARY(MAX) to UInt16, UInt32, UInt64 or SByte

Tags: .net, sql-server, casting, type-conversion

I am wondering if it is possible to convert a `VARBINARY(MAX)` value back to the original value.
The original value can be any supported SQL type (text, numeric and floating point) but also the (.NET) types `UInt16`, `Uint32`, `UInt64` or `SByte`.

These types are not supported in SQL Server so a

```
SELECT CAST([BinaryData] AS UINT) from [Data]
```

would not work here because those types are not known?

For now I am doing this convertion in my C# program but I think for performance that it would be better if it could be done on the SQL Server side. That way I would also be able to do more calculations on the SQL server instead of in the .NET program.

Any advice or solutions?

Comment: I think you need to further explain the bigger picture of your problem to get meaningful advice. I mean why are you storing as a varbinary value if the original value isn't varbinary? And when you say original value, well how do you know that datatype the original value is? And of course you can only convert to datatypes supported by SQL Server within SQL Server, so either you use an SQL Server type which works, or you do it in code. But sounds to me on the face of it that the design is wrong.

Comment: Are you also storing the source type with the binary data?

Comment: @DaleBurrell This is for a big data logging application. The client wanted every value (whatever type) in the same column so we converted every value to VARBINARY in code and inserted those in the database (could not use REAL because strings are inserted to).

Comment: @SalmanA The types are stored together with the data so I know what conversion I must do (in the C# code)

Comment: Well you already know you can't convert to .net types... so what answer are you looking for?

Comment: @DaleBurrell As I am no T-SQL expert I was still hoping that their was a way to do so. Thank you

Comment: It depends what you are trying to do with the data (which is why I was hoping you would add that to the question), a UINT can be treated as an BIGINT for example if you are trying to add them. So depending on what you are trying to do, you may be able to use the SQL Server native datatypes. So feel free to update your question which what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @lordvlad30 `The client wanted every value (whatever type) in the same column so we converted every value to VARBINARY in code` that's a horrible idea, *especially* when you have a lot of data. Big data in SQL Server when you use a good design means multiple **terrabytes**. If you dump everything in a single column querying even a few thousand rows can be slow. *Why* did the client ask for this? Did they *explicitly ask for a slow database that can't handle even tiny data amounts?* Or did they have another requirement that was interpreted as `dump everything in a column` ?

Comment: @lordvlad30 `The types are stored together with the data so I know what conversion I must do` in that case you can use proper columns. There's no need for that `varbinary(max)` column, or even storing the types anywhere. It looks like the customer asked for the [EAV *anti*pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93124/eav-is-it-really-bad-in-all-scenarios) to handle changing data without considering the *reading* costs.

Comment: @lordvlad30 SQL Server offers several ways to avoid this problem. You can use [Sparse Columns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-2017) and support thousands of columns without taking any extra space for empty columns. Indexing a sparse column converts it to a real column automagically, so you won't face a performance hit when querying. You can use XML or JSON fields to store unstructured data and query them using built-in functions. You can use calculated columns to extract values from the XML or JSON fields and even index them

Answer (score 0):

You need to check [SQL Server Data Type Conversion Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017#implicit-and-explicit-conversion) for data type conversion in SQL Server.

Please check [SQL-CLR Numeric Type Mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/sql-clr-type-mapping#numeric-mapping) i.e.: CLR Type >> Default SQL Server Type

For [max positive value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) of INT, BIGINT data type. (You can change SQL Server version in left side pane)

Please check below script for conversion from VARBINARY(MAX) to UInt16 (INT), UInt32 (BIGINT), UInt64 (DECIMAL(20)).

```
DECLARE 
    @a_INT INT,
    @a_BIGINT BIGINT,
    @a_decimal_20 DECIMAL(20),
    @bvarbin_INT VARBINARY(MAX),
    @bvarbin_BIGINT VARBINARY(MAX),
    @bvarbin_decimal_20 VARBINARY(MAX),
    @cresult_UInt16 INT,
    @cresult_UInt32 BIGINT,
    @cresult_UInt64 DECIMAL(20)

SELECT
    @a_INT = 2147483647,--INT MAX VALUE
    @a_BIGINT = 9223372036854775807, -- BIGINT MAX VALUE
    @a_decimal_20 = 99999999999999999999 -- DECIMAL(20) MAX VALUE

SELECT
    @bvarbin_INT = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),@a_INT),
    @bvarbin_BIGINT = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),@a_BIGINT),
    @bvarbin_decimal_20 = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),@a_decimal_20)

SELECT
    @cresult_UInt16 = CONVERT(INT,@bvarbin_INT),
    @cresult_UInt32 = CONVERT(BIGINT,@bvarbin_BIGINT),
    @cresult_UInt64 = CONVERT(DECIMAL(20),@bvarbin_decimal_20)

SELECT 
    @a_INT a_INT,
    @a_BIGINT a_BIGINT,
    @a_decimal_20 a_decimal_20,
    @bvarbin_INT bvarbin_INT,
    @bvarbin_BIGINT bvarbin_BIGINT,
    @bvarbin_decimal_20 bvarbin_decimal_20,
    @cresult_UInt16 cresult_UInt16,
    @cresult_UInt32 cresult_UInt32,
    @cresult_UInt64 cresult_UInt64;
```

Note: ***Be careful*** - Data will be change

1. When you convert DECIMAL varbinary value to BIGINT or INT
2. When you convert BIGINT varbinary value to INT

Comment: This is only for the supported SQL types. I am looking for a way to convert VARBINARY to unsupported types like UInt32.

Comment: @lordvlad30 there's no UInt32 in SQL Server. UInt32 is a .NET type. In SQL Server you just use a large-enough numeric type, eg `bigint` or a large `decimal`. Jiken's answer is correct. The problem is the question itself and the assumptions behind it.